# No More than 2 Apps Should be Submitted on Single Date(Logic help)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i need help with logic where a form contains parameters such App Icon,App Title,App desription,Offer Starting Date and Offer Ending date..

The Condition when i click submit button is suppose There 2 apps present on Same Date it should ask user to Select another date.. but my logic doesnt work properly.. i am able to submit even 3 apps in Same Date

Here is code

```
        public ActionResult SubmitApp(FormCollection fc)
    {

        try
        {
            if (Session["userid"] != null)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["actualprice"]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["offerprice"]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["datepickerstart"]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["datepickerend"]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["link"]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["title"]))
                {
                    ViewBag.Success = "Please fill all the fields"; return View();
                }
                else
                {

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        Submit_App sa = new Submit_App();
                        sa.App_type = fc["Fapp"];
                        sa.Actual_Price = Decimal.Parse(fc["actualprice"]);
                        sa.offerprice = Decimal.Parse(fc["offerprice"]);
                        sa.App_Description = fc["description"];
                        sa.App_Title = fc["title"];
                        if (fc["link"].StartsWith("https://")) { sa.iTunes_Link = fc["link"]; }
                        else
                        {
                            sa.iTunes_Link = "https://" + fc["link"];
                        }
                        sa.UserID = (long)Session["userid"];
                        sa.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(@fc["datepickerstart"], "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        sa.EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(@fc["datepickerend"], "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        sa.downloads_count = 0;

                        if (sa.StartDate > sa.EndDate)
                        {
                            ViewBag.success = "End Date should be higher than Start Date";
                            return View();
                        }
                        var id = Session["userid"];

                        var stdate = DateTime.ParseExact((@fc["datepickerstart"]), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        var enddate = DateTime.ParseExact((@fc["datepickerend"]), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        var contents = from u in entity.Submit_App
                                       where ((u.StartDate == stdate && u.EndDate == enddate) || (u.StartDate <= stdate && u.EndDate >= enddate) || (u.StartDate >= stdate && u.EndDate <= enddate)) //&& u.UserID == (long)id
                                       select new { u.EndDate, u.StartDate };

                        int count = 0; //s = contents.Count();
                        foreach (var item in contents)
                        {
                            //if ((item.StartDate == stdate && item.EndDate == enddate) || (item.StartDate <= stdate && item.EndDate >= enddate) || (item.StartDate >= stdate && item.EndDate <= enddate))
                            //{ 
                            count++; //}
                        }
                        if (count < 2)
                        {
                            string icons=save(Request.Files["icon"], "~/icons");
                            string images=save(Request.Files["img"], "~/images");
                            if ((images==null || images=="") || (icons==null || icons==""))
                            {
                                ViewBag.success = "Please Upload App Icon/Image";
                                return View();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sa.App_Icon = "/icons/" + icons;
                                sa.App_Image = "/images/" + images;

                                entity.AddToSubmit_App(sa);
                                entity.SaveChanges();
                                Login_Table app = entity.Login_Table.ToList().Where(x => x.UserID == (long)Session["userid"]).First();
                                app.Apps_Published = app.Apps_Published + 1;
                                entity.SaveChanges();
                                ViewBag.success = "App published succesfully";
                                return View();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.success = "2 Apps registered on your selected date choose another date";
                            return View();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else { return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login"); }
            return View();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.success = ex.Message.ToString();
            return View();
        }
        //}

    }
```

Comment: Use DateTime.Date property to check for same date. @Siddharth Koya

Comment: @ Rezoan :var contents = from u in entity.Submit_App
                                       where ((u.StartDate == stdate && u.EndDate == enddate) || (u.StartDate <= stdate && u.EndDate >= enddate) || (u.StartDate >= stdate && u.EndDate <= enddate)) //&& u.UserID == (long)id
                                       select new { u.EndDate, u.StartDate };

this is the code which i wrote for Finading same date.. could u help me from here

Comment: where you want to compare according to the data and want to omit the time part use .Date property of the DateTime object e.g: in your code: stdate.Date will retrive only the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing DateTime at the moment. This includes the hours, minutes, etc... You want to compare the Date part of the EndDate and StartDate.

```
from u in entity.Submit_App
where ((u.StartDate == stdate && u.EndDate == enddate) ||
(u.StartDate <= stdate && u.EndDate >= enddate) || 
(u.StartDate >= stdate && u.EndDate <= enddate))
select new { u.EndDate, u.StartDate };
```

should be:

```
from u in entity.Submit_App
where ((u.StartDate.Date == stdate.Date && u.EndDate.Date == enddate.Date) ||
(u.StartDate.Date <= stdate.Date && u.EndDate.Date >= enddate.Date) || 
(u.StartDate.Date >= stdate.Date && u.EndDate.Date <= enddate.Date))
select new { u.EndDate, u.StartDate };
```

Comment: @ Danexxtone : at last line select new { u.EndDate.Date, u.StartDate.Date };

for u.StartDate.Date it says "An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name"

Comment: @ Danexxtone : For the above i Modified the last line a bit :

var contents = from u in entity.Submit_App
                                           where ((u.StartDate.Date == stdate.Date && u.EndDate.Date == enddate.Date) ||
                                           (u.StartDate.Date <= stdate.Date && u.EndDate.Date >= enddate.Date) ||
                                           (u.StartDate.Date >= stdate.Date && u.EndDate.Date <= enddate.Date))
                                           select new { EndDate=u.EndDate.Date, StartDate=u.StartDate.Date };

Comment: When i press submit button:It Says

"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported"

Comment: I apologize. I was a bit too fast there. Look at the edited response for corrections. (It should be 'select new {u.EndDate, u.StartDate})

Comment: sorry for delay Danexxtone.. ur solution worked .. Much Appreciated